# Sweetaleart not posting ajax request on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have the following which is outputted via a php loop

```
<?php
    foreach ($decodeMessages as $messages) {
            print  "
         <div class='row clearfix js-sweetalert'>
                            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                            <form action='../Messages/Delete' mehtod='POST'>
                            <div class='card message-page'>
                                <div class='header'>
                                    <h2>
                                       From: " . $messages['Name'] .
                                       "<small>
                                            Email:" . $messages['Email']
                                        ."</small>
                                    </h2>
                                    <ul class='header-dropdown m-r--5'>
                                       <li>
                                            <input type='text' id='mtotal_".$key."' name='mID' value='".$messages['messageTotal']."' >
                                                <button type='button' onclick='showCancelMessage();'  data-key='".$key."' name='".$messages['messageTotal']."' id='submit' class='btn btn-default waves-effect m-r-20 cancel-button' data-type='cancel'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class='body'>";
                                        $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
                                        print openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($messages['Message']), 'aes-256-cbc', $messages['toUser'], OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
                               print "</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         ";
     }

    ?>
```

i am using the following to capture and post the following data using

```
        $(function () {
$('.js-sweetalert button').on('click', function () {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    if (type === 'cancel') {
        showCancelMessage();
    }
});
});
function showCancelMessage() {
    $('.cancel-button').click(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
        var datastring = $("#mtotal_" + key).val();
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Delete",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (!isConfirm) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../Messages/Delete",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
            mID: datastring
        },
        success: function () {
            swal("Done!", "Message succesfully deleted!"+datastring, "success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
        }
    });
});
});
}
```

content within `Messages/Delete`:

```
<?php
    $mID = $_POST['mID'];
    echo "Response: " . $mID;
?>
```

Now when i use the `print_r($_GET['mID'])` or `print_r($_POST['mID']` they both return empty array's. i'm posting on the same page so i simply added the print_r ontop of the page to see if anything is posted.

if i set a `dataType` in the ajax it returns with the error "Error Deleting".

So i'm not sure if im missing something with the ajax request, or i am simply not catching it properly using PHP ?

Comment: Initially I would suggest to place the code for the ajax response in a different PHP file.

Comment: even if i do post using `url: "../../Message/Delete"` still does not return the response. i even tried `url: "https://localsite.lcl/Message/Delete"` @iiirxs

Comment: what are you trying to return as response and how? have you set the proper headers?

Comment: for now, i just want to test if its working, so i want to grab the `mID: datastring` and echo it out after it has been posted. so in `delmessage.php` (`/Messages/Delete`) is `if (isset($_POST['mID'])) { echp $_POST['mID']; } which returns nothing

Comment: firstly try to print the response in your console: success: function(response) { console.log(response); } to see what you really get.

Comment: @iiirxs i have the following redirect in my .htaccess `RewriteRule ^Messages/Delete$ /assets/includes/delmessaging.php`

Comment: @iiirxs i used console log to output the datastring and it does work.

Comment: Console.log the response in your success function.

Comment: When i console.log the success response it responds with the entire page in the console log

Comment: That is because in your ajax response php script, you don't echo just what you want to return but the whole page. Remove all unnecessary parts and keep only the essential.

Comment: i put only the response for the console,log and the post returns a 500 error --> https://ibb.co/nxbkLp

Comment: You should post the php script where you create the ajax response.

Comment: @iiirxs i have updated my question with the ajax response, am i correctly handling it ?

Comment: It seems fine. Just add header('Content-Type: text/plain'); in your php script and set the dataType to 'text' in your ajax request.

Comment: When i add `dataType: "text"` the console outputs this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: showCancelMessage is not defined`

Comment: You might forget a comma after dataType: "text" cause this doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: i fixed it kinda, i tested the post on the same page using `#` and it turns out the post value gets set, although when i post to another page it doesn't post the values